# "python" unable to import spacy and download en_core_web_sm

Tags: python, spacy

**What I want to achieve:**

Import spacy and use it.

***What I've tried:***

When I try to import spacy on python I get **ImportError: cannot import name util** error (detail on error1)

Spacy is sucessfully installed to my device.

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2370
Following article I operated
**pip uninstall en_core_web_sm** then I got
**WARNING: Skipping en_core_web_sm as it is not installed.**

operate **python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm** give me
**TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class** error (detail in error2)

### **Error1:**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11524/513823458.py in <module>
      1 import sys
----> 2 import spacy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in <module>
     12 from thinc.api import Config
     13 
---> 14 from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
     15 from .cli.info import info  # noqa: F401
     16 from .glossary import explain  # noqa: F401

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
      2 from .dep_parser import DependencyParser
      3 from .edit_tree_lemmatizer import EditTreeLemmatizer
      4 from .entity_linker import EntityLinker
      5 from .ner import EntityRecognizer

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\attributeruler.py in <module>
      4 from pathlib import Path
      5 
----> 6 from .pipe import Pipe
      7 from ..errors import Errors
      8 from ..training import Example

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\pipe.pyx in init spacy.pipeline.pipe()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\vocab.pyx in init spacy.vocab()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\tokens\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .doc import Doc
      2 from .token import Token
      3 from .span import Span
      4 from .span_group import SpanGroup
      5 from ._serialize import DocBin

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\tokens\doc.pyx in init spacy.tokens.doc()

ImportError: cannot import name util
```

**Error2:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\akira\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\akira\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\akira\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\akira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\akira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
  File "C:\Users\akira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\attributeruler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .pipe import Pipe
  File "spacy\pipeline\pipe.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipe
  File "spacy\vocab.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.vocab
  File "C:\Users\akira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\tokens\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .doc import Doc
  File "spacy\tokens\doc.pyx", line 36, in init spacy.tokens.doc
  File "C:\Users\akira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\schemas.py", line 222, in <module>
    class TokenPattern(BaseModel):
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 205, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 491, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 421, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 537, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 634, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "pydantic\fields.py", line 641, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis
  File "C:\Users\akira\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 847, in __subclasscheck__
    return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported. See the suggested workaround: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/12659.